# How to zip a List<Flowable> using RxJava2 in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm trying to zip `List<Flowable>` using RxJava2 but it fails compiling. Code snippet is as follows

```
private fun flowInts() {
    val flows = ArrayList<Flowable<Int>>()
    for (i in 0..10) {
        flows.add(getFlow(i))
    }

    Flowable.zip(flows, Function<Array<Int>, List<Int>> {array -> // I get compile error at Flowable.zip
        array .toList()
    })
}

private fun getFlow(i: Int): Flowable<Int> {
    return Flowable.fromCallable { return@fromCallable i }
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: what is the compiler error?

Comment: The signature requires `Function<Array<Any>, R>` as `Array<Int>` wouldn't work with the underlying Java type system.

Comment: @akarnokd `Array<Any>` seems okay. but then how do i convert it to `Array<Int>`. For example what if it is `Array<SomeClass>`?

Comment: There should be a sequence operator in Kotlin that you can map them to ints, like `map({ it as Int})` or something.

Comment: Maybe you updated your question but this code compiles just fine without `Function<Array<Int>, List<Int>>`